# NextAuth build error: Type error: Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'NextAuthOptions'

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have cloned nextauthjs/next-auth-example and am running into issues using npm run build.

Link to the file with lines 1 and 2 that are causing the error: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/74bcbc39d1da4a3862b2aebce7b855c29a276597/auth.ts

[image: Error caused by build]

The same code runs well when I use ` npm run dev` Please help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: To reproduce the error: please clone https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example.git , delete either pages/api or app/api (I have deleted app/api because I wish to use client side rendering and for some reason I can't get to make it work with the latest app router) and simply run `rpm run build`